# SQL query to remove a word from a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I want an output 'HELLO DEAR FRIEND' for an INPUT 'HELLO DEAR [GOOD] FRIEND'. We can use any special character to identify the word between it to remove .

Comment: What happens if the string you want to remove is something other than "GOOD"? How are you determining what you want to remove? The square brackets? If it's being input why are you bothering to remove the  string at all? Just don't input it...

Comment: @Ben, it's a valid requirement. e.g. I have a table with messages, like `Your password is [xyzzy].`, once I've sent the message I wanted to remove the sensitive data but keep the rest for debugging purposes, e.g. `Your password is [*****].`. I solved it with a regex, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression, e.g.:

```
select regexp_replace('HELLO DEAR [GOOD] FRIEND'
                     , '\[.*\]', '') from dual;

HELLO DEAR  FRIEND
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your word begins with [ and ends with ], you can do this trick:

sql> select str from server;

> HELLO DEAR [GOOD] FRIEND

sql> select CONCAT(LEFT(str, LOCATE('[', str)-1), RIGHT(str, CHAR_LENGTH(str)- LOCATE(']', str))) from server;

> HELLO DEAR  FRIEND